# Angular 5 property binding from within the component html for the same component

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular5

I am using the property isPersonalInfoValid as a flag for a wizard component

I want the **emailform.valid** (emailForm is just a reference to the ngForm shown in the html below) to update the **component property [isPersonalInfoValid]**, I tried many ways but none worked, currently this [(isPersonalInfoValid)] is treated as a property of the emailForm which is wrong, I want to use it as a property of personal-info component.

The code below is from the *personal-info.component.html*

```
<form #emailForm="ngForm" [(isPersonalInfoValid)]="emailForm.valid">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email"
      [(ngModel)]="data.email" required email>
```

The code of *personal-info.component.ts* is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormWizardModule } from 'angular2-wizard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personal-info',
  templateUrl: './personal-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personal-info.component.css'],
  // encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PersonalInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() isPersonalInfoValid = false;
  data: any = {
    email: 'abc@gmail.com'
  };
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onStep1Next(event) {
    console.log('Step1 - Next');
  }

  onStepChanged(step) {
    console.log('Changed to ' + step.title);
}

}
```

Your help is appreciated, thanks

Edit:

I can bind the property only if I am using the component selector (in another component)  but then I can't access the form.valid property , like this

```
<app-personal-info #personalInfo  [isPersonalInfoValid]="emailForm.valid ></app-personal-info>
```

I need to make the binding so that the *form.valid* changes the property *isPersonalInfoValid*

Edit 2:

The code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxbbyw)

Comment: Can you add html and component of EmailForm.

Comment: Actually this EmailForm is just a reference for the ngForm shown in the HTML , it is not a custom component, I will edit it to be clear in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No need** to create another variable to check validity of the form. Get access to `form` where you need. In your case parent need to get access of `form` in the child component. It can be solved in two ways by official documentations:

1. Little More Code. You can access to child components by injecting them into the parent as a **ViewChild**. Read more: [Parent calls an @ViewChild()](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild)
2. Simple and Easy way. If you want to access child only in parent component template, use local variables(#var). Read more: [Parent interacts with child via local variable](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-interacts-with-child-via-local-variable)

For you case I already **@ViewChild** approach. It gives you full access to child component, but also little more code than second approach using local variables.

[ViewChild Decorator. Official doc.](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Get access to child `PersonalInfoComponent` component in parent **WizardComponent**:

```
 ...
 @ViewChild(PersonalInfoComponent)
  private personalInfo: PersonalInfoComponent;
 ...
```

In child **PersonalInfoComponent** get access to `emailForm` similarly as above:

```
@ViewChild('emailForm') emailForm: NgForm
```

Then, in parent `WizardComponent` you can get `emailForm` throw `PersonalInfoComponent` child component. And pass it to `wizard-step` component as this `personalInfo.emailForm.valid`

**WizardComponent.html:**

```
  ...
  <wizard-step [title]="'Personal Information'" [isValid]="personalInfo.emailForm.valid" (onNext)="onStep1Next($event)">
          <app-personal-info #personalInfo></app-personal-info>

  </wizard-step>
  ...
```

[StackBlitz EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etrft7)

Comment: Actually I want to use the most simple format to do it as you said,however, if I use this way I get the following error:
[Angular]
Can't bind to 'form' since it isn't a known property of 'app-personal-info'.

Comment: Please note that emailForm is only a reference for ngForm inside the component personal-info , so this name is probably only seen inside the same html of the component

Comment: @AhmedElkoussy, of course you can't get it. Create in your `app-personal-info` `@Input() form` property

Comment: ok, I tried it but still can't bind to the inner form of the component

I get this error:
[Angular] Identifier 'emailForm' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member

Comment: @AhmedElkoussy, create a StackBlitz code example, I can help you here

Comment: Thanks @Yerkon , I will make the example on StackBlitz & put it here

Comment: I have added the link to the code on StackBlitz in the end of the question, something is missing so it can't run , but at least you can see the files better there, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168057/discussion-between-yerkon-and-ahmed-elkoussy).

Answer (score 0):

Use as normal assignation not as ngModel

```
isPersonalInfoValid = email.valid
```

Comment: You mean inside the same place, right ? like this ?
<form #emailForm="ngForm" isPersonalInfoValid="emailForm.valid">
I tried this also , but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: how you are checking the changed value?

Comment: The form.valid is automatically assigned based on the validity of the form, I have added more details to the question to make it more clear

Comment: Now the problem is :
1- inside the component, I can easily access form.valid but not the component property itself isPersonalInfoValid
2- outside the component, using the selector, I can access isPersonalInfoValid but not the form.valid property

Comment: im not getting you.where you are having your form and personal component?

Comment: My personal component has a form , I want that form.valid property to change the property isPersonalInfoValid to use that property in other components

Answer (score 0):

try emailForm.form.valid

```
<app-personal-info #personalInfo  [isPersonalInfoValid]="emailForm.form.valid ></app-personal-info>
```

Comment: if I use this, the emailForm is not defined, this emailForm is only known inside the the component personal-info